# Reactjs: input field has value but showing as empty

Tags: html, reactjs, input

Facing a weird issue. I have an input field in my react app.
I am setting the value of my input field using the `defaultValue` prop.
But my input field is not populating. Its showing as **empty** ( "" ). But i can see the value in its value attribute in the dom. 
[image]

Here are the react props of that input

[image]

Any idea what i am missing here?

Comment: can you add html code in the question please?

Comment: May be try using 'value' instead of 'defaultValue'

Comment: How do you handle `value` of your `input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `defaultValue` only on uncontrolled components, but your input have `onChange` prop, and that makes it controlled. You should set your default value through the `value` prop.

https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html - here some info about it.